# Direction of $ds$ in $E\cdot ds$

Tags: electrostatics, potential, work, potential-energy, integration

I have started a course on electromagnetism (EM) online, but I have some confusions in the math related to the work or potential energy.

Say we have a force field, and two positions A and B, and a path between A and B. We choose some coordinate system and want to calculate the work done. So we simply add up little $\vec F\cdot d\vec s$ along the path, where $d\vec s$ is a little path along the larger path.

- $Q_1$: It is intuitive to take the direction of path from A to B. But we take it to be in increasing direction of unit vectors.
  Why is that?
- $Q_2$: Furturmore, I don't get at all how the endpoints of integral determine the direction of $d\vec s$ (or if they even do). On what other factors does this direction depend?
- $Q_3$: Also in the gauss law we do have a definite direction of $d\vec A$( "radially" outwards) whereas here we only have direction of $d\vec s$ depends upon the choice of co-ordinate system and unit vector. If both of them ($\int E\cdot d\vec A$ and $\int E\cdot d\vec s$) are just continuous sums. So why such a major difference in directions?

Answer (score 1):

This is a continual source of confusion to students (and some instructors). In path integrals like this one, the path must eventually be described in terms of some coordinate system. The description entails 1) defining the *coordinate change* part of the integral (d$\vec{s}$) in terms of the specific unit vectors and coordinate names (spherical, cylindrical, rectangular, ellipsoidal, etc) and 2) writing the limits of the integral in terms of the chosen coordinate system.

It is ultimately the limits, described in terms of the coordinate variables, being extremely consistent with positive directions as defined by the $d\vec{s}$ vector that determines the motion (positive or negative) along the path.

Consider the simple example of calculating the vector which describes a change in the position vector when moving from $(x_1,y_1,0)$ to $(x_2, y_2, 0)$:
$$\Delta \vec{r} = \int_{x_1}^{x_2}\hat{i}\mathrm d x +\int_{y_1}^{y_2}\hat{j}\mathrm d y+ \int_{0}^{0}\hat{k}\mathrm d z$$

This is independent of whether $x_1$ is greater or less than $x_2$. I am moving from one $x$ value to another, and the $\hat{i}\mathrm d x$ term tells me what the positive direction would be so that $x_1\to x_2$ is well-defined in terms of the coordinate system.

The endpoints do not determine the direction of d$\vec{s}$. They determine the direction of the path in terms of coordinates which are described by d$\vec{s}$:
$$\int_a^b \vec{F}\cdot\mathrm d \vec{s} = -\int_b^a \vec{F}\cdot\mathrm d \vec{s},$$
if $\vec{F}$ is a conservative force. Notice the only thing which changed is the limits. d$\vec{s}$ is the same in both cases in this example.

I'll defer Q3 to someone else. :)

Comment: Is it necessary that dx, dy and dz >0? I guess not.

Comment: The differentials tell you what to integrate. The limits tell you where you start and where you end up. If the limits say "go from x=5 to x=-4", you don't add a negative sign to the integrand; you evaluate the integral, then apply the limits.

Answer (score 0):

Let's make it simple by assuming that the force is constant at $5$ units in the $\hat x$ direction and the displacement is from position $x=2$ t0 $x=6$.

The work done is $5 \times (x_{\rm final} - x_{\rm initial})  =5 \times (6-2)=+20$ units.

If the displacement is from position $x=6$ t0 $x=2$ then the work done is
$5 \times (x_{\rm final} - x_{\rm initial})  =5 \times (2-6)=-20$ units.

For the first example in vector notation the work done is
$5 \,\hat x \cdot (\vec x_{\rm final} - \vec x_{\rm initial})  =5 \,\hat x \cdot (6\, \hat x-2 \, \hat x)=+20$ units where $\vec x$ is a position vector.

So now look at the integral with work done $\displaystyle \int_{x_{\rm initial}}^{x_{\rm final}}\vec F \cdot d\vec x = \int_{x_{\rm initial}}^{x_{\rm final}}(F\,\hat x) \cdot (dx\,\hat x) = \int_{x_{\rm initial}}^{x_{\rm final}}F\, dx$

and because $F$ is constant the work done is $\displaystyle F\int_{x_{\rm initial}}^{x_{\rm final}} dx =F(x_{\rm final}-x_{\rm initial})$.

The order of the terms in the bracket $(x_{\rm final}-x_{\rm initial})$ depends entirely on the lower and upper limits of the integral.

So whether $dx$ is positive or negative depends on the limits of the integral.

This means that your statement *But we take it to be in increasing direction of unit vectors* is not correct and hopefully your Q2 has been answered?

*Also in the gauss law we do have a definite direction of $d\vec A$ ("radially" outwards) . . . .*

This might be a convention adopted by some but it does not have to be so.
The thing you must do is to choose a convention and stick with it.